# Give a name to an array of JSON objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api

I am new to JSON and i am trying to get data from database in Sql Server with Asp.net Web Api.

My Output json Array is Like this:

> [ { "f0": 9608, "f1": 1461, "frbDescField_F56": "Jan", "f2": "1461",
>   "f3": "179:48"}]

But the output of the Json should be similar to the following code:

> { "restaurants": [ { 
>       "f0": 9608, "f1": 1461, "frbDescField_F56": "Jan", "f2": "1461", "f3": "179:48"}] }

and My Code is:

```
public IEnumerable<VI_TimeTotalMontly> Get(int id, string id1)
{
    using (tfmisEntities Entities = new tfmisEntities())
    {
        var result = Entities.VI_TimeTotalMontly.Where(e => e.F0 == id && e.F2 == id1).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

How do I change my codes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can build a strongly typed anonymous object to match the desired output. You would also need to change the return type of the action as `IEnumerable<VI_TimeTotalMontly>` would just return a collection, when you want an object response

```
public IHttpActionResult Get(int id, string id1) {
    using (var Entities = new tfmisEntities()) {
        var restaurants = Entities.VI_TimeTotalMontly
                              .Where(e => e.F0 == id && e.F2 == id1)
                              .ToList();

        var result = new {
            restaurants = restaurants;
        };

        return Ok(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: I would prefer this answer as it does not involve operations during runtime like when we use dynamic. It is better to get things done in compile time. Unless you have no other option try to use this method.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a `dynamic` object to wrap your result:

```
dynamic output = new ExpandoObject();
output.restaurants = result;

return output;
```

Comment: This is fine but incomplete. You would also need to explain changing the action signature.